# Name claim returning username and not name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4

I am having an issue with some of the values returned in the id token by Identity server 4.  The id token and the userinfo endpoint are both returning username instead of name for the name claim.

```
{ 
  ........

  "preferred_username": "JohnD",
  "name": "JohnD",
  "email": "xxx@xxx.dk",      

  .....
}
```

As you can see both preferred_username and name have the same value.  If i check in the database.

- Username: JohnD
- Name: John Doe
- Email: xxx@xxx.dk

I copied the [DefaultProfileService.cs](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/63a50d7838af25896fbf836ea4e4f37b5e179cd8/src/Services/Default/DefaultProfileService.cs)  Directly from identity server 4.

So my code is the same

```
/// <summary>
    /// This method is called whenever claims about the user are requested (e.g. during token creation or via the userinfo endpoint)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        context.LogProfileRequest(Logger);
        context.AddRequestedClaims(context.Subject.Claims);
        context.LogIssuedClaims(Logger);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

I can see that context.Subject.Claims appears to be populated with this data already and i cant seam to remove it or over ride it.

I am not sure how to fix this

### Update

I tried adding preferred_username claim instead and now i am getting doubles.

```
"preferred_username": [
"John Doe",
"JohnD"
 ]
```

I also tried to remove the claim from the list but its read only.

Comment: What are you using in IS4 itself for signing-in users? e.g. Identity or is it something else?

Comment: Asp .net identity with entity framework core.

Comment: The IS4 + Identity integrations registers its own [`IProfileService`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/ProfileService.cs#L20), which really just uses [`UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#L75). You might need to customise something there.

Comment: I copied the default DefaultProfileService.cs from the identity server project. it has not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thanks to [Kirk Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078/kirk-larkin) for pointing me in the right directly via a comment.

I actually did have an overload for UserClaimsPrincipalFactory already in my code i just went ahead and copied the offending lines from the official code and swapped things around.

However i am now wondering if its my understanding of the difference between name and preferred_username are not incorrect.

```
 public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<long>>
    {
        public CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole<long>> roleManager,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
            : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {  
            var userId = await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            var userName = await UserManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity("Identity.Application", 
                Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType,
                Options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType);
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, userId));
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType, user.Name));
            id.AddClaim(new Claim("preferred_username", userName));
            if (UserManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
            {
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(Options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType,
                    await UserManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user)));
            }
            if (UserManager.SupportsUserClaim)
            {
                id.AddClaims(await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user));
            }
            return id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Usually, `preferred_username` would be something like `jskeet` and `name` would be something like `Jon Skeet`. The ASP.NET Core Identity doesn't have the concept of a name without extension and so username is all it can really use for that.

Comment: Yeah thats the same conclusion i came to.   My only issue now is that one of my wsfed additions is doubling the name claim.  Everything else is working fine.